# output pig fs command to a file or a variable

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to monitor the files in my HDFS system.
Currently, the way I am doing it is very painful: `fs -ls -R /river/entity/files;`.

This command output the result in the console log file. And then I need to copy/paste the result into a file to use it... which is not efficient at all. Using **PIG**, is there a simple way to output the result of the command directly into a file?

EDIT: Thx for the answers but I haven't been clear enough. Sorry !
I cannot use terminal. I execute only a pig script and I want my result in HDFS. Is it possible to do that only on hadoop side?

Comment: Just for the record: This may be possible, but using Pig for this will always be a workaround/hack, not a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can ! In fact you can execute any shell command in your Pig script like this :

```
%declare dummy `hdfs dfs -ls -R /river/entity/files | hdfs dfs -put - hdfs://nn.example.com/hadoop/myfile.log`
```

But you should consider that Pig statements does not executed in the order that appear in your script !

Comment: This will not output the result in HDFS right? the myfile.log will be on local. But I have no access to local.

Comment: Now should write into hdfs, the `-` make the put command read from stdin

Comment: This would be a nice hack, @StevenBENET this seems to be designed to write to HDFS, can you confirm whether it works?

Answer (score 0):

simply type in your terminal:

```
$hadoop fs -ls -R /river > your/path/to/file.txt
```

or write command in shell script example `file.sh` contains below code and then run your shell script:

```
hadoop fs -ls -R /river > your/path/to/file.txt
```

If you are using Pig Grunt shell or Pig script then use [shell utility commands](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/cmds.html#shell-cmds)

example `file_name.pig` contains code `fs -ls -R /river/entity/files`

then run your pig script from terminal like `PIG file_name.pig > your/path/to/file2.txt`

Comment: Thanks for that but I cant use the terminal. I want everything to be done in pig if possible. The output would be stored in HDFS